# Quicker alternative to twisty-tie on a bread bag?

Tags: food, storage, fastener

It feels so inefficient that when I want to just get a slice of bread I have to completely untwist the tie on the bread bag, untwist the bag, get the slice out, twist up the bag, wrap the twisty-tie around it, and twist it all back together.

The disposable bread bag clips that come on some loaves are a little better, but they're not on all bags and it seems that there should be something even quicker and easier.

Answer (score 5):

My usual solution to this problem is to just twist the opening of the bag and fold it under the loaf of bread when setting it back on the shelf.

Unfortunately my wife isn't convinced that it's an effective way of keeping the bag sealed.

Comment: My wife hates the "Spin-n-tuck" technique, too.

Comment: I discovered that the "Spin-n-tuck" does NOT work if you have an infestation of Pharaoh ants. I don't know how they do it but I have found the persistent lil guys enjoying my homemade bread.

Answer (score 5):

As far as quick and easy goes, a good quality bag clip might be what you're looking for. I don't personally use them on bread bags currently, but I do use them on everything from produce to rice with good results. They're very easy to release and clip back on, and close the bag when it's flat, rather than twisted, reducing your effort of getting bread out of the bag to three steps (unclip, remove the slice, reclip), as opposed to your current six steps listed.

Comment: Hi @Allison. There’s been a comment on my answer that I may have duplicated yours. If so, I apologise - and I’ll delete mine if you wouldn’t mind adding to your answer a picture of the clips you were thinking of.

Answer (score 3):

A one-gallon food storage bag with a plastic "zipper" should do the trick. Zip open, take out a slice, zip closed.

[image: sliced bread in zippered food storage bag]

When you first buy the bread, it will most likely be in a plastic bag. Remove all the bread from that bag and throw that bag away. Get 2 one-gallon food storage bags, since a whole loaf won't fit in one bag. Put half the loaf in each bag and zip them shut. (You could even store one half of the loaf in the freezer to prolong its freshness.)

Comment: I hope you meant: "Remove all the bread from that bag and _recycle it_"

Comment: if you store one half of the bread in the freezer, it has to be sealed very very tightly or it will become stale.

Answer (score 3):

[Try a heavy-duty clip](http://www.thedealsdiscount.com/index.php?main_page=popup_image&pID=295), like a bulldog clip (*the link is to a picture on thedealsdiscount.com* - see picture below).

[image]

Scrunch up the end however you like, and clip it on. To get your bread, just squeeze the clip to get it off.

Comment: I think Allison C suggested this exact solution before you did.

Comment: @Stan I thought she was referring to long, purpose-made-for-bags ‘clips’ like [these](https://www.yesstyle.com/en/livesmart-set-of-6-plastic-bag-sealing-clip-as-shown-in-figure-one/info.html/pid.1061388008?cpid=1061388007&tcuc=AUD%3Fgclid%3DCjwKCAjw4sLVBRAlEiwASblR-6z4UFL-fxmpBQck2Pa8oFOUL_P32HAyM9lxF-Ix6Cd6gsx3l7eaZxoCc6sQAvD_BwE). On re-reading, I see what you mean. After looking at the link in this comment and noting the name of that product, let me know if you still think my answer is really a duplicate. If so, I’ll delete my answer.

Comment: Nooo. It's not up to me. I've done the same thing—didn't carefully review all the existing answers before posting my similar one. Jus' sayin'

Comment: @Stan I understand; I'd just like your opinion on this.

Comment: Your nice comment to AllisonC regarding your error communicates all the right sentiment. Let's all move on. We're here to help others and enjoy the sharing. Oh, and by the way: a picture is better than a link which can break leaving a 404 (page not found) error. Most everything is covered in the Help Centre (? icon) in the site menu. My opinion is that you seem like a nice person.

Answer (score 3):

My grandfather had a good solution to this. At least, I think it's good. With the bread inside, give the bag a spin or two, keeping the spun part as close to the loaf as possible. Stand the bag/loaf on its heel. Without unspinning, fold the opening of the bag down around the loaf, so that the opening end of the bag is inside out with the front of the loaf inside it. It is a little neater and more secure than the "spin and tuck" mentioned in another answer, but still requires no additional "hardware."[image]

Comment: Hi fwkb, Welcome to Lifehacks.stackexchange. Nice illustration and clear instructions.

Comment: This solution does work, and keeps it locked with a minimal amount of air inside which also helps conserve the bread.

Answer (score 2):

Would it be possible to ***SAVE*** one disposable bread bag clip and ***REUSE*** it for subsequent bags of bread that come with the undesirable labour-intensive twisty tie.

What a wacky idea.

Comment: Yes I've considered that, but like I said in my question, it seems like there should be an even better solution than those things. Sometimes they are annoying to take off and put on.

Comment: @Marathon55 I feel your pain.

Answer (score 1):

**Rapid access** versus **shelf-life** concession.

A purpose-built counter-top storage container called a bread-box is faster for storing and retrieving one or more slices of bread. The full sliced loaf of bread is placed in the container which has a large front-opening door allowing easy, fast access to one or more slices at your soul discretion.

There is a downside in that the container allows air access greater than would a sealed, close-fitting air-tight plastic bag. The ambient dry room air will allow the bread to become dry as it ages.

A tighter-fitting box that restricts the amount of airspace will increase the product shelf life at the expense of time and effort to replace the product without damage each time it is opened and closed.

Answer (score 1):

A good stout spring style clothes pin works wonders at our home. We use them to keep a lot of bags closed. Give the top of the bag a twist, and clip it on! Unclip it and the bag is as good as open.

Comment: This would be a variation of the answer given first by Allison C and then repeated by Lawrence the next day, several hours before you.

Comment: Different kinds of clips, each with their own advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

There is a thing called a "cord lock" that you might like. I did a search for it and found it,there are pictures of some. Get one, tie the ends of a shoelace together. Put a the looped shoelace through it, pull to tighten. Store it with the shoelace in the cord lock.